# How to print to python console elapsed time every x seconds while a statement is executing?

Tags: python, debugging, logging

I am running a clustering algorithm, and I want to see how long it has been running for with logging messages. Is there a way to log the elapsed time every minute for example, that will print out to the console while my clustering algorithm runs in parallel? Do I have to parallelize these processes?

Comment: may this help ? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-schedule-library/#:~:text=Schedule%20lets%20you%20run%20Python,when%20a%20task%20should%20run.